# WP7 -- Context Menu Forces Black Background for Listbox

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0, windows-phone

This is probably an easy one... I have a Listbox with a ContextMenu embedded in it, and every time the ContextMenu appears, the Listbox changes its background to opaque black. How do I prevent this from happening?

Here is some sample XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="FolderItems" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemListBox}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding FolderItems}">
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu> 
       <toolkit:ContextMenu 
         x:Name="FolderContextMenu"
         Margin="20"
         Background="WhiteSmoke"
         BorderBrush="Black"
         BorderThickness="1.0"
         Closed="ContextMenu_Closed">
              <toolkit:MenuItem Loaded="ContextMenuItem_Loaded" 
                  Opacity="0.0" Margin="5" Background="Transparent"
                  Click="ContextMenuItem_Click" Name="ContextMenuDelete">
                  <toolkit:MenuItem.Header>
                      <TextBlock Text="delete" FontFamily="Segoe WP Bold"/>
                  </toolkit:MenuItem.Header>
              </toolkit:MenuItem>
          </toolkit:ContextMenu>
  </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
</ListBox>
```

Thanks

**Update**

I still haven't figured out why the entire listbox goes black when the context menu appears. I've set everything I can think of to a transparent brush.

Comment: You haven't actually set a listbox background, so shouldn't it be black (or white, depending on theme) in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried applying a transparent background to the listbox and every item contained within it, but the black background still shows. Does the context menu have some sort of setting that can affect its target in this way?

Comment: I saw this and thought 'Did I write this?' Having the exact same issue currently.

Comment: @RyanM were you able to make any progress towards this?

Comment: @willmel I'm still struggling with this issue. I cannot release my app until I fix this. It's very frustrating. I've tried changing all brushed on item templates, item container templates, item panel templates, and listbox styles to transparent... the listbox still goes black. I've concluded that it must have something to do with the contextmenu defined in the listbox and not in the item template. Thing is though, in my design, the contentmenu cannot be in the item template.

Comment: @RyanM ah.. I am actually having this issue in the ItemTemplate(DataTemplate)

Comment: @willmel I moved my content menu into the item template and rearranged my code to support that implementation. At present, only the selected item in the listbox goes black. So, now I have the exact problem you have. This looks better. Thanks m8.

Comment: @RyanM Yeah ;/ Wish we could find a real resolution though.. My background is a client's image, so even this black won't be acceptable. If it seems ok, make sure to try it in the other background-theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this for my situation by opening up the toolkit (downloading the source: [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)), and editing the color values myself in *ContextMenu.cs* . Then, I rebuilt and targeted the dll that I created rather than the one from the installer.

The only issue is that I will now need to do this application specific, but at least I can have a resolution. I believe also that if you set *IsZoomEnabled=false*, it won't have this behavior in the first place, but it's a different experience.

Here's my edited version: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/afifPHQD)

Check out the lines like this, they're the ones you'll need to change:

```
// Create a layer for the element's background
                UIElement elementBackground = new Rectangle
                {
                    Width = ownerElement.ActualWidth,
                    Height = ownerElement.ActualHeight,
                    Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
                };
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. It should do the trick. I never thought about editing the toolkit. Slick.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way to do this.  For some reason MS Access complements the colors when using a list box.  If you set the foreground to red, it will show green, etc.

So, set the background color to black (0) and the foreground color to white (16777215).  Counter-intuitive but it works is MS Access 2002.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the template you're using I can't say for sure but you've probably hardcoded a background value but not considered the different states of the list items and the default state colour/value is being displayed

Comment: Humm... I Edited the item container style of the listbox and set the background brushes to none for each of the states, and the problem persists. Even if I only have one element in the listbox, when I tap-hold and the context menu appears, the entire listbox background goes black.